# TypeScript + Express: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'

Tags: typescript, express

I have express@4.17.2 and node@16.13.0 running in a small app:

The route is defined like this:

```
import express from 'express';
import urlController from './url-controller';

const router = express.Router();
router.use(express.json());
router.post('/', urlController.createShortUrl);

export default router;
```

The controller file like this:

```
const createShortUrl = (req: Express.Request, res: Express.Response) => {
  const { url } = req.body;
  ...
}
```

I am getting `TS2339: Property 'body' does not exist on type 'Request'` when running the `tsc` compiler. Any ideas why `body` is missing?

Comment: Do you import Express with `import express from 'express';` in your controller file? Then it should be `req: express.Request` and so on. Otherwise try `import { Request, Response } from 'express';` and `(req: Request, res: Response) => ...`. And `@types/express` is also installed?

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I wasn't importing express in my controller file. I assumed by installing `@types/express` that it would work it out, but doing it explicitly has solved it.